# Securing an Ikea countertop to Ikea drawers (SALJAN and ALEX)

Tags: screws, warp, fasteners

As the title suggests, I'm having a few second thoughts about how to mount my 98" Saljan countertop to two sets of Alex drawers.

I've already bought three 14 gauge steel channels that I'll be putting in the middle to support the space between the drawers, so my main point of contention is where I'm going to bolt down the counter on the drawers.

I understand the weight of the counter should keep things from moving around, but I'd much rather secure it down with some bolts screwed into threaded inserts I'll be putting into the countertop. Over-engineering, just like my old man. (Can you over-engineer cardboard furniture?)

On the Alex schematics, there's four pre-drilled holes for people that want to mount their desk top to the Alex, but it's all the way in the center. There's also barely any space between the two sets of holes.

Would it be better to drill through one of the corner holes that is normally there for mounting wheels?

[image]

**TL;DR** Here's a little screencap to illustrate what I mean. The two red squares are where they normally want you to run screws through to mount a desk top to the Alex drawers. The four green circles is where I'm wondering if it would be better from a weight distribution/securing/warp/sag preventing standpoint to drive those fasteners through instead. I'm using a 98" particle board Saljan countertop, and that thing is heavy. I've already reinforced the middle with three 14 gauge steel channels.

Comment: Accepting this is a WAG, with the info you gave (including the extra bracing, I would expect you not to get too much difference between using the Green  places vs the red ones unless you plan to have people dancing on your desk, at which point a leg in the middle would be more useful.  So I'd say go with the red ones, or the green ones or both.  since they are really just holding the top from sliding around, nothing more.

Comment: Who... is this Alex?

Comment: *"Would it be better to drill through one of the corner holes that is normally there for mounting wheels?"* This is surprisingly subjective. I'd say do it if you want to, but I judge that there's zero benefit to be gained — plenty of things are centre-fastened in woodworking. *"...weight distribution/securing/warp/sag preventing..."* Weight distribution is already guaranteed by the flat tops of the Alexes, no? You could argue there's a strength bump distributing the fasteners but that's an engineering-level query (and probably only relevant in that context!) Warp and sag aren't issues.

Comment: *"I've already bought three 14 gauge steel channels that I'll be putting in the middle to support the space between the drawers"* What's the unsupported span, and expected load??? The Saljan is standard countertop material, at nearly 4cm it's plenty stiff; pretty long unsupported spans are perfectly routine for this stuff, e.g. where an under-the-counter washing machine and drier are intended to go.